# Select all single quotes from the first row using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

Say I have a string which would render as:

> ('First Name', 'Last Name')
>
> ('Thomas', 'Jenkins')
>
> ('Samuel', 'Adams')

In reality the string would look something like this (unformatted):

```
('First Name', 'Last Name')\n ('Thomas', 'Jenkins')\n ('Samuel', 'Adams')
```

How would I, using just Regex, select the the single quotes from just the first row from this text (everything before the first `\n`)? *Note that this is just example text and the actual text could have several more fields of single quotes.*

My ultimate goal here would be to use a replace to change those single quotes `'` to double quotes `"`.

I see that I can select the first using something like `^[^\n]*`, but how in the world do I select the single quotes from the bunch?

Thank you for your time.

**Edit:**

The end result would be something like the following (first row has double quotes):

> ("First Name", "Last Name")
>
> ('Thomas', 'Jenkins')
>
> ('Samuel', 'Adams')

Comment: So you only want to convert the single quotes from the first instance to double quotes and keep the rest single quotes?

Comment: Well, I'd like all single quotes on the first row changed to double  quotes (4 in this example, but there could be more)

Comment: Why "*using just Regex*"?

Comment: do you need to keep the line breaks ?

Comment: I don't necessarily have to keep the line breaks. @DavidThomas, I recognize there's other ways to do this, but I am making several edits to this string and would like to keep using regex if possible. If for no other reason than the thrill of beating a seemingly impossible task.

Comment: What would you do with a name that contained an apostrophe such as `('Fred', 'O'Neil')` which won't even parse correctly as a quoted string?

Comment: "*...the thrill of beating a seemingly impossible task*" - while I'm not intending to criticise your requirements, or insult you, this is a *terrible* reason to over-complicate something. This would be far easier using regular expressions *in addition to* other solutions.

Comment: @StephenP, in the case of creating a SQL script, single quoted strings are interpreted simply as text, I need them to be column names (thus double quote).

Comment: @DavidThomas, I totally understand. I am fairly proficient in regex but would like to know if there was a way to do it that I am not thinking of in the context of using regex.

Comment: Yeah that's fine. I didn't realize it was overcomplicating things. I was hoping there was an easier solution within regex. Thank you for your time.

Comment: As a 'for example' (I couldn't add to my previous comment, *sigh*): http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/ee9Lr8v0/

Comment: If JS supported variable length look-behind, there would be a way to express "all single quotes on the first line". Without that feature, there isn't.

Comment: Ah, good to know @Tomalak. Thanks David for the link.

Comment: @KJPrice See my answer. With variable-length lookbehinds you could do the same thing in one regex-replace step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While this *may* be possible using "*just regular expressions*", I must confess that I still find regular expressions something of a dark art, and would recommend that you use `String.prototype.split()`, `Array.prototype.map()` and then `Array.prototype.join()` *in addition to* regular expressions:

```js
var str = "('First Name', 'Last Name')\n ('Thomas', 'Jenkins')\n ('Samuel', 'Adams')",
  // splitting the String on the new-line characters:
  strArray = str.split('\n');

// using Array.map to create a new Array:
document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = strArray.map(function(line, index) {
  // the first argument (here 'line') is the array-element over which we're iterating,
  // the second (here 'index') is the index of that array-element in the array.

  // if the index is greater than 0, we return the original unchanged array element,
  // otherwise (if it is equal to 0) we replace all the ' characters with " characters,
  // using the global 'g' switch:
  return index > 0 ? line : line.replace(/'/g, '"');
  // then we join the Array back together, as a string, with new-line characters:
}).join('\n');
```

```html
<div id="demo"></div>
```

References:

- [`Array.prototype.join()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).
- [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).
- [Guide to JavaScript regular expressions (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).
- [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split).

Comment: You're very welcome indeed! I'm just a little sorry that I couldn't conceive of a regular expression to do as you originally wanted (and would, I suspect, prefer).

Comment: "__I still find regular expressions something of a dark art__" Can you please explain what do you mean by "__dark art__" ?

Comment: I find them difficult to understand, and needlessly complex; especially when used with an irregular language, such as written language (whether English, Italian, etc...).

Answer (score 2):

To identify all single quotes on the first line of the input we would need to check any single quote and find out if it is only preceded by non-newline characters. In a regex dialect that supports variable-length lookbehinds this would go like `/(?<=^.*)'/g`, because `.` is every character except the newline.

However, JS does not support this. It only supports lookaheads.

There is a sneaky way of emulating (variable-length) lookbehinds in JavaScript through reversal of the input string and subsequent use of lookaheads.

It's not very efficient and I probably would not use this in production code, but here you go.

```
var input = "('First Name', 'Last Name')\n ('Thomas', 'Jenkins')\n ('Samuel', 'Adams')",
    output = input.split("").reverse().join("").replace(/'(?=.*$)/g, '"').split("").reverse().join("");
```

returns

```
("First Name", "Last Name")
('Thomas', 'Jenkins')
('Samuel', 'Adams')"
```

---

To make this a bit more readable we could augment the String prototype.

```
String.prototype.reverse = function () {
    return this.split("").reverse().join("");
};
```

so we would end up with

```
input.reverse().replace(/'(?=.*$)/g, '"').reverse();
```

Comment: That's awesome! I love the one-liner.

Comment: @KJPrice It's an ugly hack if you ask me, at the very least for the problem at hand. But the approach is worth keeping in mind, might come in handy some day.

Answer (score 2):

This is a javascript regex solution.

```
var string = (
    "('First Name', 'Last Name')\n" +
    "('Thomas', 'Jenkins')\n" +
    "('Samuel', 'Adams')"
);

var result = string.replace(/\('([^']*)', *'([^']*)'\)(.*)/m, '("$1", "$2")$3');

$('body').html('<pre>' + result + '</pre>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mcb2eeun/1/

To explain te regex:

```
\(        # opening bracket
'         # opening single quote
([^']*)   # capture anything zero or more times except for single quotes ($1)
'         # closing single quote
,         # comma
 *        # a space zero or more times
'         # opening single quote
([^']*)   # capture anything zero or more times except for single quotes ($2)
'         # closing single quote
\)        # closing bracket
(.*)      # capture the rest of the string ($3)
```

The `/m` at the end makes the `.` character also match newlines.

Comment: Yep, I stand by my own answer, and the assertion therein: "*I still find regular expressions something of a dark art*" - but even so: an up-vote is yours! ... *but only if* you can clearly explain how that regular expression works, using human language... ;)

Comment: Thanks! Yeah this works. In one of my comments on the issue I mentioned that there could be more single quotes on the first line from more fields. I should have added that to my question. +1 for an all regex solution though. Thanks!

Comment: Well fine then, *have* your up-vote... :) (Seriously, though: well done; it's - perhaps - not as versatile as required, but that's still a difficult solution to come up with.)

Answer (score 1):

Just split according to newline characters and do a find and replace on the first line.

So... split

```
var arr = string.split('\n');
```

and then replace just the first line

```
arr[0] = arr[0].replace(''','"');
```

Comment: apologies... just saw "using regex". feel free to ignore this if it doesn't suit your needs

Comment: You didn't try this, did you? Hint: it won't work as required.

Comment: Yeah, looks like there is not a straight forward way to do this using regex. Thanks for your answer. I might just end up using this.

Comment: The most reasonable solution in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

You can also loop over the return from a string match using your first-line regular expression and replace the single quote to double. Not very optimized but it uses only regular expression matching and replacing on the same string per your requirement and will work for any first line of any paragraph.

```
var rgx = /^([^\n]*?)'/g;
var str = " ('First Name', 'Last Name')\n ('Thomas', 'Jenkins')\n ('Samuel', 'Adams')";
var matches;
while ((matches = str.match(rgx)) !== null) {
  str = str.replace(matches[0], matches[0].replace(/'/, '"'))
}
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rgthree/rjngtuL7/

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = "('First Name', 'Last Name')\n ('Thomas', 'Jenkins')\n ('Samuel', 'Adams')";
string = string.replace(/\('First Name', 'Last Name'\)/img, '("First Name", "Last Name")');
alert(string);
```

---

Output:

```
("First Name", "Last Name")
 ('Thomas', 'Jenkins')
 ('Samuel', 'Adams')
```

Comment: Thank you, but this seems to just replace the entire first line. I really need to isolate the single quotes in the case of this inevitably changing.

Comment: I'm sorry but I cannot understand what you need. what do you mean by "isolate the single quotes" ?

Answer (score 0):

This is a javascript regex that matches the first brackets and uses a callback to replace the single quotes.

```
var string = (
    "('First Name', 'Last Name', 'Post name')\n" +
    "('Thomas', 'Jenkins')\n" +
    "('Samuel', 'Adams')"
);

var result = string.replace(/\( *'[^']*'(:?, *'[^']*')+\ *\)(.*)/m, function(stuff) {
    return stuff.replace(/'/g, '"');
});

$('body').html('<pre>' + result + '</pre>');
```

http://jsfiddle.net/mcb2eeun/2/